# How to Generate a unique Coupon Code In the Django Admin panel for bulk

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have used this code in models.py  I'm getting the error of Gift is not defined and models are not showing in the Django admin panel#
from django.db import models
import secrets
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UniqueCodes(models.Model):
"""
Class to create human friendly gift/coupon codes.
"""

```
# Model field for our unique code
code = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

@classmethod
def post_create(cls, sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Connected to the post_save signal of the UniqueCodes model. This is used to set the
    code once we have created the DB instance and have access to the primary key (ID Field)
    """
    # If new database record
    if created:
        # We have the primary key (ID Field) now so let's grab it
        id_string = str(instance.id)
        # Define our random string alphabet (notice I've omitted I,O,etc. as they can be confused for other characters)
        upper_alpha = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"
        # Create an 8 char random string from our alphabet
        random_str = "".join(secrets.choice(upper_alpha) for i in range(8))
        # Append the ID to the end of the random string
        instance.code = (random_str + id_string)[-8:]
        # Save the class instance
        instance.save()

def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % (self.code,)
```

post_save.connect(Gift.post_create, sender=UniqueCodes)

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing Gift to UniqueCodes and it worked.